CiviCRM and Mailchimp sync solution for PHP 8.2 and latest Civi version?
I moved my CiviCRM installation from a Drupal 7 site to Wordpress and I have updated Civi to the latest version (5.78.3) with PHP 8.2. The migration was very painful but it went fine. In Drupal 7 I was using the "Mailchimp CiviCRM integration" extension and I was surprised to discover that it is compatible with PHP 8.2 and the latest civi. Given that it is one of the most popular extension in CiviCRM, I was wondering what solutions other users have adopted. I won't consider Mosaico, I have tried Zapier but the actions available are very limited.
I was wondering if someone was able to make the extension work in an environment similar to mine, or if someone has attempted to fix the code.
Thanks!

We used the other extension https://docs.civicrm.org/mailchimpsync/en/latest/

we're the original developers of the extension and could look to make it PHP 8.x compatible. Please feel free to reach out to Veda Consulting and we can take it further.

Thank you for your response and for offering to help! Given the over 1,000 installs, I believe there’s a shared interest in updating this extension. If Veda Consulting could outline, as a first step, what would be required to make the extension compatible with PHP 8.x—whether that involves resources, collaboration, or community support—it would be helpful for transparency and allow others to potentially assist.
